# exit code of system() call with a single scalar argument in Perl

Tags: perl

There is a `system()` call in a Perl script with multiple pipes, using a single scalar argument. The call looks more or less like this:

```
system("zcat /foo.gz | grep '^.{6}X|Y|Z' | awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$6}' | bzip2 > /foo.processed.bz2");
```

The file in question (`foo.gz`) is quite large, about 2GB compressed in size. I guess that's why it was originally done via a system call.

**Questions:**

The problem now is, that this system call always seem to return 0, whether one of the system commands fail or not. I assume this is because it gets invoked via `sh -c '...'`. Is that correct?

Is there a way to check if a `system()` call was successful if only a single scalar argument is passed?

Is there a better way to process a large file like this, in a way thats equally or more efficient (in terms of speed mainly)?

Thanks for any hints as I am not really familiar with Perl.

Comment: If you using grep through a system call in perl... you are not programming in perl :)

Comment: I know, this is some old Perl code written by someone else and I am also not really experienced in it, what a combination :) Anyway, maybe you give me some ideas how to do it better and in more elegant way?

Comment: Also $2, $3 parts reference variables in perl code, not in awk code. Because double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. When you do a system call, the value returned is the last value in the pipeline. Thus, you're getting the status code of the `bzip2` command.
2. The reason the program is doing this is because the people who wrote the program probably didn't know any better. I've seen Perl programs use system calls for finding the basename of the file, doing a find, and even doing a copy/rename/move. These are all things that can be done faster and easier inside the Perl program. And, you don't have the whole Windows/Unix compatibility issues.

You're always better off using Perl modules for things like this. In this case, I bet the Perl modules will be even faster than the shell pipeline, and you'll have more control over the entire operation.

There's a set called [IO::Compress](http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/IO-Compress-2.043/) that can handle both Zip and BZip2.

I use [Archive::Zip](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Archive-Zip-1.30/lib/Archive/Zip.pm) which is a great module, but you want to use the Bzip2 compression algorithm, and `Archive::Zip` can't handle that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions about the modules, I'll take a look at them.

Comment: Did you mean to say `can't handle that`?

Comment: @TLP - Yes, you're correct Archive::Zip **can't** handle that [bzip2 compression]

Answer (score 2):

`system()` returns what the `/bin/sh` shell returns. When multiple commands are pipelined, the shell forks a new process for each of them and the status code of the last command in the chain is returned, in this case `bzip2`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments and answers, I'd do it like that now:

```
$infile =~ s/(.*\.gz)\s*$/gzip -dc < $1|/;
open(OUTFH, "| /bin/bzip > $outfile") or die "Can't open $outfile: $!";
open(INFH, $infile) or die "Can't open $infile: $!";
while (my $line = <INFH>) {
    if ($line =~ /^.{6}X|Y|Z) {
        # TODO: the awk part...
        print OUTFH $line;
    }
}
close(INFH);
close(OUTFH);
```

Please feel free to comment and vote up/down.

Comment: Awk line could do split on line like: "my @fields = split(/\s+/, $line);". This should how awk does it, it's splits with IFS variable, this is close enough, I guess :). Also it is nicer to use variables instead of BIG LETTER thingy, I forget how are they called, like: 'open my $out_fh, "| /bin/bzip > $outfile" or die $!;'. Look at [perl101](http://perl101.org/files.html).

Comment: `open my $infh, '-|', '/bin/zcat', $infile or die $!` would perhaps be a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

You'd be better doing the text processing from within perl itself - that's what perl's for :)

system() only ever returns 0 or 1. To capture actual output, try calling it via backticks: `command` rather than system('command')

Comment: This is factually inaccurate. "The return value is the exit status of the program as returned by the wait call. To get the actual exit value, shift right by eight. [...] Return value of -1 indicates a failure to start the program or an error of the wait(2) system call [...]."